# Pusherapp/Websocket not connecting

Tags: websocket

I'm trying to use pusherapp here but chromium's console just gives me "WebSocket is closed before the connection is established." My JS is below, any ideas as to what might be the problem?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var pusher_key = "<%= Pusher.key %>";
   var pusher_channel = "thirsty-<%= Rails.env %>";
   var pusher = new Pusher(pusher_key, pusher_channel);
   pusher.bind('push_comment', function(content) {
     comment_html = '<li><p>' + content + '</p></li>'
     $(comment_html).prependTo('#comments');
   });
});  
</script>
```

Comment: when you console.log "pusher_key" and "pusher_channel" are the properties correct?

Comment: yep they're both showing the correct values

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking the reason for the following error:

> WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

This is actually a generic WebSocket error which is logged by the browser when an attempt is made to close the WebSocket connection (by calling `webSocketInstance.close()`) before the connection has even been established.

The error is triggered by the Pusher JavaScript library try to close a connection, but is caused by bad network or browser conditions (e.g. online/offline reporting). All all cases (that I'm aware of) the Pusher JavaScript library will retry connecting until those connections are resolved (e.g. the Internet connection is restored).

More information and an example in the following answer:

[What does "WebSocket is closed before the connection is established" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487828/what-does-websocket-is-closed-before-the-connection-is-established-mean/12503628#12503628)

A couple of points on the code above:

- the `Pusher` constructor has a first parameter which is the application key. The second parameter is a map of key value options. So, you shouldn't be passing in a channel name as the second parameter. More info on the [`Pusher` constructor here](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_connect#connecting)
- The `pusher.bind` call is actually deprecated (docs being updated now). For channel events you should bind directly on the channel using [`channel.bind`](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#bind-events) and for connection events you should bind on the [`Pusher.connection`](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_connect#connection-states) object.

Comment: This answer is sadly missing a lot of context and therefore unusable.

Comment: @Obie hopefully the update clarifies things and make the answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

1. It could happen if the internet connection is too slow or disconnected.
2. Cross check the pusher Credentials.
3. It you have **cluster** in pusher channel app make sure you write it in you code.