# What does "WebSocket is closed before the connection is established" mean?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm using JavaScript and the [Union platform](http://www.unionplatform.com) How would I go about diagnosing this problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 31):

If you go to http://jsbin.com/ekusep/6/edit and view the JavaScript console you'll see the 'WebSocket is closed before the connection is established' logged. I've tested this in Chrome.

In this code what it means is that `ws.close()` was called (by user code) before the connection was even given a chance to be established.

So, the cause of this error is if code attempts to close the WebSocket connection before it's had a chance to actually connect.

Comment: I have done a search through my entire project directory and found no instance of `ws.close()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Take a look at the [WebSocket API MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) and you'll see a `close` method listed. If you don't see that used in your project it may simply mean that WebSocket connections are not closed.

Comment: Turns out ActionCable defaults to port 3000 and I wasn't on port 3000 lol. Keep that in mind for the future :)

Comment: @KendallWeihe how do you check what port are you on? I am having the same problem, but I was not able to fix.

Comment: @Felipe Maion I do have the same problem ws://10.30.10.52:8080/spring-ng-chat/chat/237/rl5h8_6h/websocket

Comment: @leggetter > What do you mean the code attempts to close the WebSocket connection??
You mean server side code or client side code??

Comment: @ZAJ in this answer I'm referring to testing in Google Chrome and provide a link to run in the browser. So, this is for a web browser client.

Answer (score 14):

In React you need to add this to your `useEffect` in `return`

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const socket = new WebSocket(address);


        return () => {
            if (socket.readyState === 1) { // <-- This is important
                socket.close();
            }
        }
}, []);
```

However it not only the best solution! You need [use hooks](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks) instead of using socket connection directly in view/component it can prevents multiple creation of socket connection.

Also socket connection should closed by backend if its not in use, whenever frontend is communicating or not.

Comment: Is there a way to know that the socket is actually being destroyed?

Comment: I don't know actually but every State of WS has unique number you can find out what happened when it's destroyed or any other things happened with this number

Comment: When the `useEffect` callback is called multiple times, you'll connect to the server multiple times. In the code above, the connection is not cleaned up. That's a **memory leak**. We should still call `close` even if the connection has not been made yet, this happens when the useEffect clean up function is called before the connection is established.

Answer (score 3):

In React, if you subscribe to websockets in `useEffect`, this error is **fine** when running in Strict Mode. React would create the subscription [twice in Strict Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897567/7365866), and the first 1 is thrown away immediately, be sure to close the first one!

### The other [react answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73769657/7365866) (by Bambier) is wrong...

...because it causes a **memory leak**. You end up with **2 subscriptions** in React Strict mode (and local development). **Why?** It doesn't clean up the first subscription caused when the component renders twice. If the first component hasn't connected yet, you won't close it (`socket.readyState === 1` is false). Eventually, the first WebSocket will eventually connect too.

This can also happen in production, when the component is re-rendered faster than the connection is formed. Your client and websocket server take longer to connect (larger distances/latencies), so this can definitely happen.

It hides the browser warning message, but adds a bug instead.

Answer (score 1):

In React if you're writing some kind of App's wrapper component and connect to websocket in useEffect like so:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8001')    
  setWS(ws)

  return () => {
    ws.close()
  }
}, [])
```

this is due to React's strict mode **intentional remounting of all components twice** to help debug side effects, even if you have empty array of dependencies. See [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar) for more info

## Solutions

1. Turn off React's strict mode (either by removing `<React.StrictMode>` in ReactDOM.createRoot for example in Vite, or by settings `reactStrictMode: false` in config for example in Next.js)
2. OR you can use React's refs since they are a simple way to manage state between renders:

```js
const [ws, setWS] = React.useState<WebSocket | null>(null)
const wsRef = React.useRef<WebSocket | null>(null)

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!wsRef.current || wsRef.current.readyState === WebSocket.CLOSED) {
    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8001')
    wsRef.current = ws
    setWS(ws)
  }

  return () => {
    if (wsRef.current && wsRef.current.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      wsRef.current.close()
    }
  }
}, [])
```

Answer (score -1):

For anybody else coming in to find an answer, apart from what @leggetter has mentioned above, in my case, it turned out that I was missing the *port number* while establishing a connection. I was using socket.io if that helps.

```
http://websocket.service:8000
```

Answer (score -5):

Just open the port in server
ufw enable