# rails4 actioncable was work in staging, not work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, puma, actioncable

I'm deploying a Rails 4 app using Capistrano, Puma and Nginx. The deployment to the staging environment works, but deploying to the production environment gives an error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.com:28080/' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

I've read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487828/what-does-websocket-is-closed-before-the-connection-is-established-mean) but it isn't helpful for me.

`ps aux | grep 28080` shows a process listening on 28080.

Can you tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: I've reworded your question to make a bit more sense—please let me know if I've misunderstood anything!

Comment: Where are you trying to deploy to?  If it's Heroku, Heroku only accepts SSL websocket connections so your ws url should start with an "wss//..." and you have to make sure you properly set up an SSL point on Heroku as well: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Comment: I'm not deploy to Heroku.
In actioncable [Consumer Configuration](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/README.md)
'If you host your production server via https, you will need to use the wss scheme for your Action Cable server'
But i'm try to add a wss, but it not work too .
however i'm deploy in app relace Standalone, it work well in staging and production.