# Why is useEffect running twice?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Log =  ()  =>  {
    useEffect(()  => {
        console.log('Running ...')
    },[])

    return(<p>here</p>)

}

export default Log;
```

Whenever this code runs, I get
**Running...** messages twice in the browser console.

I think it should run once, as I have an empty second parameter in useEffect.

Can anybody explain why it is getting run twice?

Comment: It depends on the context. Most likely it's something up on the tree.

Comment: Sounds like you have [`<StrictMode>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) enabled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React 18, useEffect is getting called two times on mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/react-18-useeffect-is-getting-called-two-times-on-mount)

Answer (score 38):

This is due to <[StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)> most likely in your root tree.

**What is strict mode?**

> StrictMode is a tool for highlighting potential problems in an application.

**How does it make `useEffect()` run twice?**

> It activates additional checks and warnings for its descendants, or in other words... renders twice.

`Note:` Strict mode checks are run in development mode only; they do not impact the production build.

Comment: For a more detailed answer visit  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72238236/15288641

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent running useEffect() twice by using the following way,

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
const Log = () => {
    // initiate dataFetch
    const dataFetch = useRef(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Running ...')

        // start:: prevent executing useEffect twice
        if (dataFetch.current)
            return
        dataFetch.current = true
        // end:: prevent executing useEffect twice
    }, [])

    return (<p>here</p>)
}

export default Log;
```

Answer (score 1):

If useEffect doesn't have any dependencies, the component itself is called only once.

This answer will help you.

[React Hooks: useEffect() is called twice even if an empty array is used as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar)

Answer (score 1):

As the dependency list of useEffect() sets empty, "console.log" will automatically run whenever the Log component re-renders.
I think there might be some changes of context or parent component from component tree.
Please check your project structure.

```
<ContextProvider.Provider value={setGlobalState}>
  <ParentComponent>
    <Log/>
  </Parent Component>
</ContextProvider.Provider>
```