# why console.log inside the useEffect runs twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, console.log

i'm currently working with react project, which gets data from api and
show it on the console.

although i wrote the console.log() just one time inside the useEffect hooks (with the [articles] dependency ), the web browser's console.log always shows the console.log two times like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQAxP.jpg)

but i don't know reason why..

in my thought when the 'articles' state set by first useEffect hook, the second useEffect hook activates and console.log should be run only one time.. but it didn't.

here is my code

```js
const NewsList = () => {

  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=> {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=kr&apiKey=''
      `);
      setArticles(response.data.articles); 
    }
    getData();
  },[])

  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log(articles);
  },[articles])
  
  
  return (
    <div className="newsListBlock">
      <NewsArticle article={article}></NewsArticle>
      <NewsArticle article={article}></NewsArticle>
      <NewsArticle article={article}></NewsArticle>
      <NewsArticle article={article}></NewsArticle>
      <NewsArticle article={article}></NewsArticle>

    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72370066/10535718 does this answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect is run every time the dependencies change.

1. The first value, on the first update of the component, is `[]` (the initial state).
2. The second value, after the data-getting effect runs, is whatever you get from newsapi.org.

Additionally, if you're using `<StrictMode>` and a React development build, [certain lifecycles](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) can be invoked twice. See e.g. [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-wood-2rkq2e?file=/src/App.js); if you remove the `<StrictMode>` from `index.js`, you'll see less console.logs.

Comment: I was thinking the same, however, his screenshot shows that the variable has values both times, so the first value, given your theory, should be empty, no?

Comment: @CasperBang See my edit; this is StrictMode playing tricks on us. OP is just not showing the first empty console.log.

Comment: @CasperBang browser console output shows only current state if the logged value was an object. i.e. if you log object, then change it, browser will show this changes.

Comment: @Jaood_xD That wouldn't happen with React state, since you need to always reassign them in order for a component to rerender.

Comment: as AKX said i just captured the part of console.log. and after i removed the '<StrictMode>', the console properly showed the state only one time. this was the problem with the strickmode. thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Stab-the-cake You should keep strict mode on, though – it's there to keep you from making mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do something after render.

So this `useEffect` will run once on the first render of the component, and then run a second time due to the use the `setArticles` function which update `articles`.