# UseCallback in combination with StrictMode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I have the following code snippet in use while wrapping my whole React application with `<React.StrictMode>`.

```
function Quiz() {

    const fetchData = useCallback(
        async () => {
            console.log("hiho");
        },
        []
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [fetchData])

    return (
        <>
        </>
    )
}
```

For the initial load of my application `fetchData` is being called twice within my `useEffect()`. I am a bit puzzled as I assumed that `useCallback()` would prevent this (even though StrictMode calls the rendering twice).

Should I be worried that `fetchData` get's called twice? In my case `fetchData` returns **random data** which then has the side effect that the data changes during the render process on dev.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the fetchData from the useEffect dependency array. I believe that should render it just once.

```
function Quiz() {
    const fetchData = useCallback(
        async () => {
            console.log("hiho");
        },
        []
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
        </>
    )
}
```