# Why is my (super simple) React component initially always rendered twice?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on some optimization algorithms in the context of a larger React project. While testing some things I have encountered the following behavior of React: Even the most simple React component is initially always rendered twice. I am wondering why.

Here is my source code that demonstrates this behavior:

`App.tsx`

```tsx
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Test1 from './components/Test1';

function App() {
  return <Test1 />;
}

export default App;
```

`Test1.tsx`

```tsx
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const Test1 = () => {
  // useRef hooks
  const counter: React.MutableRefObject<number> = useRef<number>(0);

  // useEffect hooks
  useEffect(() => {
    counter.current++;
    console.log(counter.current.toString());
  }, []);

  return <div>Test1</div>;
};

export default Test1;
```

`counter.current` is initially always increased to 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "render twice"? Are there two elements in the DOM or two `console.log`?

Comment: Are you using react strict mode? If so, this is expected behavior from React's Strict Mode - https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html . More details can be found in the blog post for React v18 here: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html

Comment: Maybe possible beacuse of the strict mode in development. [Check this](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

Comment: To answer the first question: Yes, I do always get two "console.logs".

Comment: So, I guess what's the point of @widepeepohappy that it does not "render twice", just render once and then it re-renders, which is desired in that case :)

Answer (score 4):

It is because of the `React.StrictMode`. Updating the Ref forces the component to re-render. See [React Hooks: useEffect() is called twice even if an empty array is used as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar) for further information.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks to those who commented super quickly and pointed out that this is expected behavior from React's "Strict Mode"!

I can confirm that this is the right answer to my question.

I have just run a production build that does not show this behavior any more. I only get one "console.log" and the counter only increase once.