# react firebase makes multiple requests

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from firebase and pass it to a state array but firebase makes 2 requests

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const uid = '';
    const dbRef = ref(getDatabase(app));
    get(child(dbRef, `users/${uid}/${params.hey}`)).then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        snapshot.val()['rows'].forEach(element => {
          var elemets = {
            key: element['id'],
            link: element['link'],
            image: element['image'],
            placeholder: element['placeholder'],
          }
          setMyArray(arr => [...arr, element]);

        });
      } else {
        console.log("No data available");
      }
    }
    ).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })
    return () => { }
  }, [])
```

[image: See example]

Should show only one request once

````
        {myArray.map(() => (
          <h1 >one request</h1>
        ))}    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely wrapping your app in  `<React.StrictMode>`, which *only during development* causes `useEffect` to fire twice. It's intended to hell catch bugs when useEffect has unintended side effects. You could change it to set the array from scratch instead of merging it with the prior state, remove strict mode, or add a cleanup return from `useEffect`

Comment: worked, thank you, i removed React.StrictMode