# Why are multiple canvases being made in my Phaser/React app?

Tags: reactjs, phaser-framework

I am trying to develop a phaser3 application with React. I am just setting up the first canvas for the Phaser.Game. Here is my App.js from the create-react-app.

```js
import "./App.css";
import Phaser, { Game } from "phaser";
import PhaserMatterCollisionPlugin from "phaser-matter-collision-plugin";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [game, setGame] = useState(null);
  // Creating game inside a useEffect in order to ensure 1 instance is created
  console.log("before use effect");
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Going into useEffect");
    console.log(game);
    if (game) {
      console.log("game detected. stop creation");
      return;
    }
    const phaserGame = new Phaser.Game({
      width: 512,
      height: 412,
      backgroundColor: "#333333",
      type: Phaser.AUTO,
      parent: "survival-game",
      scene: [],
      scale: {
        zoom: 2,
      },
      physics: {
        default: "matter",
        matter: {
          debug: true,
          gravity: { y: 0 },
        },
      },
      plugins: {
        scene: [
          {
            plugin: PhaserMatterCollisionPlugin,
            key: "matterCollision",
            mapping: "matterCollision",
          },
        ],
      },
    });

    setGame(true);
    return;
  }, [game]);
}

export default App;
```

I used useEffect() with useState in order to prevent multiple game instances, but for some reason I am still getting a duplicate canvas and can see that it is running through the useEffect multiple times. [console.log of the react app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQC8Y.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks: useEffect() is called twice even if an empty array is used as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar)

Comment: You should use `ref` instead of state for that.

Comment: For this, you should probably use a ref instead of a state atom.

Comment: You can also do `return () => phaserGame.destroy()` which would be even better

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useEffect is running twice on mount in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/useeffect-is-running-twice-on-mount-in-react)

Answer (score 4):

You should use a ref instead of state for the game object. Here's a small custom hook that sets up a Phaser.Game based on a given configuration:

```
function usePhaserGame(config) {
  const phaserGameRef = React.useRef(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (phaserGameRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    phaserGameRef.current = new Game(config);
    return () => {
      phaserGameRef.current.destroy(true);
      phaserGameRef.current = null;
    };
  }, [] /* only run once; config ref elided on purpose */);
  return phaserGameRef.current;
}

const config = {
  width: 512,
  height: 412,
  backgroundColor: '#333333',
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  parent: 'survival-game',
  scene: [],
  scale: {
    zoom: 2,
  },
  physics: {
    default: 'matter',
    matter: {
      debug: true,
      gravity: {y: 0},
    },
  },
  plugins: {
    scene: [
      {
        plugin: PhaserMatterCollisionPlugin,
        key: 'matterCollision',
        mapping: 'matterCollision',
      },
    ],
  },
};

function App() {
  const game = usePhaserGame(config);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the reference personally in nextjs I still have two canvases and I don't understand why?

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useRef } from "react";
import { type Game as GameType } from "phaser";

const loadPhaser = async (
  config: Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig
): Promise<GameType | null> => {
  const Phaser = await import("phaser");
  return new Phaser.Game({ ...config, type: Phaser.AUTO });
};

export const usePhaserGame = (config: Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig) => {
  const phaserGameRef = useRef<GameType | null>(null);

  const cleanScene = () => {
    if (phaserGameRef?.current) {
      phaserGameRef.current.destroy(true);
      phaserGameRef.current = null;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (phaserGameRef?.current) return;
    loadPhaser(config).then((result) => (phaserGameRef.current = result));
    return () => cleanScene();
  }, []);

  return { game: phaserGameRef?.current };
};
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35070997)