# My custom React hook method "useFetch" is running 8 times when called

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

Hope anyone is able to help me with a custom react hook.

My custom react hook "useFetch" is running 8 times when called.
Can anyone see, why it is running 8 times when the custom "useFetch" hook is called?

I am a bit new to React, but it seems like I am using useEffect method wrong. Or maybe I need to use another method.

UseFetch hook method:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useFetch = function (
  options = {
    IsPending: true,
  },
  data = {}
) {

  // load data
  const [loadData, setLoadData] = useState(null);
  // pending
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false);
  // error
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // method
    const fetchData = async function () {
      // try
      try {
        // set pending
        setIsPending(true);

        // response
        const response = await fetch(data.url, data);

        // handle errors
        if (response.status !== 200 && response.status !== 201) {
          // throw new error with returned error messages
          throw new Error(`Unable to fetch. ${response.statusText}`);
        }

        // convert to json
        const json = await response.json();
        // set load data
        setLoadData(json);

        // set error
        setIsError(false);
        // set pending
        setIsPending(false);

        // catch errors
      } catch (err) {
        // set error
        setIsError(`Error fetching data: ${err.message}`);
        // set pending
        setIsPending(false);
      }
    };

    // invoke fetch data method
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  // return
  return {
    loadData,
    isPending,
    isError,
  };
};

export default useFetch;
```

Comment: Where did you call this hook?

Comment: Every time the state changes hooks are called

Comment: Hi @Enfieldli 
I am calling the method here: https://gist.github.com/qaiswardag/35ff8d52b951b37e199029a6af5ab4e4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why useEffect running twice and how to handle it well in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react)

Answer (score 2):

Everytime you change a state in a hook, the component that has the hook in it will rerender, making it call the function again.
So let's start counting the renders/rerenders by the change of state:

1. Component mounted
2. `setIsPending(true)`
3. `setLoadData(json)`
4. `setIsPending(false)`
   (depending if it's successful or not you might get more state changes, and therefore rerenders, and therefore hook being called again)

So 4 is not 8, so why are you getting 8?

I presume you are using React18, and React18 on `development` and `StrictMode` will call your useEffect hooks twice on mount: [React Hooks: useEffect() is called twice even if an empty array is used as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar)

What can you do to avoid this?

First of all, check on the network tab how many times you are actually fetching the data, I presume is not more than 2.

But even so you probably don't want to fetch the data 2 times, even though this behaviour won't be on `production` and will only be on `development`. For this we can use the useEffect cleanup function + a ref.

```
const hasDataFetched = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  // check if data has been fetched
  if (!hasDataFetched.current) {
    const fetchData = async function () {
      // fetch data logic in here
    };
    fetchData();
  }
  // cleanup function
  return () => {
    // set has data fetched to true
    hasDataFetched.current = true;
  };
}, []);
```

Or as you suggested, we can also add data to the dependency array. Adding a variable to a dependency array means the useEffect will only be triggered again, when the value of the variable inside the dependency array has changed.

(Noting that `data` is the argument you pass to the useFetch hook and not the actual data you get from the fetch, maybe think about renaming this property to something more clear).

```
useEffect(() => {
  // check if data has been fetched

    const fetchData = async function () {
      // fetch data logic in here
    };
    fetchData();

}, [data]);
```

This will make it so, that only if loadData has not been fetched, then it will fetch it. This will make it so that you only have 4 rerenders and 1 fetch.

(There is a good guide on useEffect on the React18 Docs: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - I learned a lot from your feedback.
Yes, I was using StrictMode.

Comment: Using a ref with an `if` statement in `useEffect` should be avoided as much as possible. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react

Answer (score 0):

Every time you change the state within the hook, the parent component that calls the hooks will re-render, which will cause the hook to run again. Now, the empty array in your `useEffect` dependency should be preventing the logic of the hook from getting called again, but the hook itself will run.

Comment: Hi
Based on the hook, what should I insert in the empty array? 
I am calling the method here: https://gist.github.com/qaiswardag/35ff8d52b951b37e199029a6af5ab4e4

Comment: If you wanted the hook to be fully correct, the dependency array should be listing `data.url`. Otherwise it's totally fine. I know the hook "running" eight times is strange but that's actually expected. Your logic within the hook will properly one run once