# useEffect fires two times in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I use useEffect to make an api call only one time after the component is rendered. But it renders two times and I don't understand why. Thank you for your hints.

```
    useEffect( ()=> {
        // load all pipelines
        console.log("getting all pipelines");
        const api = new Api();
        api
        .get_pipelines()
        .then(response =>{
            getPipelines(response.data.sort((a,b) => (a.pipelineState > b.pipelineState) ? 1 : ((b.pipelineState > a.pipelineState) ? -1 : 0)))
            })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("error getting existing pipelines", error);
            if(error.response.status === 500 || error.response.status === 404){
                openBanner("Cannot load existing pipelines", "error")
            }
            });
    }, [openBanner]);
```

Comment: Is openBanner updated after the component mounts? That would trigger a rerender

Comment: could be due to react strict mode if u are in dev

Comment: I've tried it also without openBanner and an empty array. Yes I'm in strict mode. How can I change it?

Comment: Can you show the full component? It is also possible that the parent is rendering twice.

Comment: if you are using react 18, you may think about it is this cause your component render  2 times: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state

Comment: Yes, I use react 18...Thx all for your hints. Strange behavior!

Comment: @mm1975 in ur index.js can you try commenting out the <ReactStrictMode></ReactStrictMode>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an empty dependency array, it indicates to React that the effect does not depend on any props or state changes, so there is no need to re-run the effect when they change. This is useful when you have a side effect that needs to be executed only once when the component mounts, but not on subsequent re-renders.

```
useEffect(() => {
    /* global google */
    google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById("signInDiv"), { theme: "outline", size: "large" })
  }, [])
```

In this specific example, the effect is responsible for rendering a Google sign-in button using the Google Accounts API. By passing an empty dependency array, React ensures that the button is rendered only once when the component mounts, and not on subsequent re-renders.

Comment: Pls see my comments. I already tried an with an empty array

Comment: Oh, I think this happened coincidentally at the same time.