# OpenSeaDragon doesnt display a slide

Tags: reactjs, openseadragon

I don’t understand what the problem is, OpenSeaDragon doesn’t display the slide that I take from the API to the screen.

**Here is a full code**

```
import '../../../App.css'
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect,useRef  } from "react";
import OpenSeadragon from "openseadragon";


function CaseImage(){ 
    const { id } = useParams();
    const viewerRef = useRef(null);
   


    const [imageSize, setImageSize] = useState(null)


  useEffect(()=>{
        fetch(`http://localhost/api/case/slide/GetDimensions?file_id=${id}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) =>setImageSize(result.data))
  },[id])
    
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (imageSize && viewerRef.current) {
      const viewer = OpenSeadragon({
        id: 'openseadragon-viewer',
        prefixUrl: '',
        constrainDuringPan: true,
        tileSources: {
            getTileUrl: function (level, x, y) {
                return "http://localhost/api/case/slide/GetTile/" + id + "/" +
                    level + "/" + x + "_" + y;
              },
          zoomPerScroll: 2,
          overlap: 10,
          height: imageSize.height,
          width: imageSize.width,
          tileSize: 256,
          minLevel: 8,
         
        },
        zoomInButton: 'zoom-in',
        zoomOutButton: 'zoom-out',
        homeButton: 'home',
        fullPageButton: 'full-page',
        nextButton: 'next',
        previousButton: 'previous',
      });

      viewerRef.current = viewer;
    }

    return () => {
      if (viewerRef.current) {
        viewerRef.current.destroy();
      }
    };
  }, [imageSize, id]);
  
    return(
        <>
               
    <div id="openseadragon-viewer" style={{ height: "700px", width: '100%' }}></div>

    <div id="openseadragon-buttons" className="Panel">
      <button id="zoom-in">Zoom In</button>
      <button id="zoom-out">Zoom Out</button>
      <button id="home">Home</button>
      <button id="full-page">Full Page</button>
     </div>
   </>
    )
}

export default CaseImage
```

I tried to give a straight direct like  this

**http://localhost/api/case/slide/GetTile/397a03fc-6ebe-4278-ae86-7be34a5b9034/8/0_0**

instead of this
**http://localhost/api/case/slide/GetTile/" + id + "/" +
level + "/" + x + "_" + y**

but it didnt help

Comment: Do you have an error related to this in the console?

Comment: Hello, there are no errors in the console

Comment: You are sure of uploading the image through this [link](http://localhost/api/case/slide/GetTile/397a03fc-6ebe-4278-ae86-7be34a5b9034/8/0_0). To be sure, open this [link](http://localhost/api/case/slide/GetTile/397a03fc-6ebe-4278-ae86-7be34a5b9034/8/0_0) in a new tab.

Comment: yes, i am sure d

Comment: It sure looks like it should work! There are all sorts of things you can do to debug... Add a console.log to make sure the viewer is being created. Take a look at the network tab of the developer tools to see if it's attempting to load in any image. Try a simple image first: https://openseadragon.github.io/examples/tilesource-image/

I'm noticing there's no extension on your URL... I don't think that should be a problem, but I guess you could try adding an extension. 

One unrelated thing:  zoomPerScroll shouldn't be part of the tile source; move it out to the main options.

Comment: Hi, i figured out how to solve it, the problem was in the sizes

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your `CaseImage` component is probably mounted twice. This can happen for various reasons, e.g. if [React StrictMode is on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60619061/12689370). So the viewer is constructed and then immediately destructed at the end of the first mount.

If you set `viewerRef.current` to `null` after destruction, the viewer will be reconstructed on the second call, and this might be enough.

However, a better approach (which avoids the double construction) would be to create the viewer as a response to the `<div>` going into or out of the DOM. One way to achieve this is (approximately)

```
const setRef = useCallback((element: HTMLDivElement | null) => {
    if (viewerRef.current) {
        ... <destruct old>
        viewerRef.current = null; // not strictly necessary
    }
    if (element) {
        ... <create viewer on element>
        viewerRef.current = viewer;
    }
}, []);
...
return <div ref={setRef} {...etc}></div>
```