# Why is firebase being initialized twice?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm initializing firebase when the react app runs. Since I'm calling initFirebase on component mount, it should be called only once. But in my console, I see "Initialized firebase app" twice. Why is the function runnning twice?

The relevant code:

```
function App() {
  const [FBApp, setFBApp] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let app = initFirebase();
    setFBApp(app);  
  }, [])

  const router = createBrowserRouter([{
    path: "/",
    element: <HomePage />
  },
  {
    path: "/admin",
    element: <AdminPage />
  }
])

  return (
    <FirebaseAppContext.Provider value={{FBApp, setFBApp}}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </FirebaseAppContext.Provider>
  )
}


//initFirebase.js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const initFirebase = () => {
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  console.log("Initialized firebase app", app);
  return app;
};

export default initFirebase;
```

Comment: in dev useEffect always run twice - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar

Comment: Ah, it seems it's due to the strict mode, which is enabled in my app. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initFirebase` function is running twice because you are using React 18 and `StrictMode`. React 18 introduced a change in the default behavior of `useEffect` in development mode when using `StrictMode`. `StrictMode` is a tool that helps you find potential problems in your app by activating additional checks and warnings. One of these checks is to render the component twice on mount and unmount, which causes useEffect to run twice as well. This is done to detect any side effects that are not properly cleaned up or depend on the render order. To learn more, see [Why does useEffect run two times? - flaviocopes.com](https://flaviocopes.com/react-useeffect-two-times/)

To avoid running twice, you can use cleanup function in `useEffect` hook.

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let app = initFirebase();
  setFBApp(app);
  return () => {
    app.delete();
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove <React.StrictMode> from index.js This code will be

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

React StrictMode renders components twice.

one more reason can be this code is triggering re-render in parent component that is making it run it twice.