# UseEffect Rendering Twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, html5-canvas, jsx

I am building an whiteboard application and to create the white board I was playing with html canvas element.
I was trying to print a word on canvas but I really don't understand why but it is putting it twice on the screen
`

```
 import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

    const WhiteBoard = () => {
      const canvasid = useRef();

      useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasid.current;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.font = "30px Impact";
        ctx.rotate(0.1);
        ctx.fillText("Awesome!", 50, 100);

        // Draw line under text
        var text = ctx.measureText("Awesome!");
        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(50, 102);
        ctx.lineTo(50 + text.width, 102);
        ctx.stroke();
      }, []);

      return (
        <>
          <div>WhiteBoard</div>
          <canvas ref={canvasid} style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}></canvas>
        </>
      );
    };

    export default WhiteBoard;
```

`

I was expecting the code to print Awesome on the canvas once but It is being printed twice, I tested with debugger and It shows that useEffect is being run twice But I only want it to run once when it is mounted on the screen

Comment: https://dev.to/sidak/magic-useeffect-running-twice-2c58

Comment: you can check your ```index.js``` and see if you have ```React.StrictMode``` wrapping your app. It makes your component rendering twice

Comment: Thanks that was the issue removing `React.StrictMode fixed it`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though OP already solved his issue with my comment above, but removing `StrictMode` is actually not a good solution here.

Quoting from the [React official docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode):

> We recommend wrapping your entire app in Strict Mode,
> especially for newly created apps. If you use a framework that calls `createRoot` for you,
> check its documentation for how to enable Strict Mode.

So, what's the good solution other than removing `StrictMode` ?

Well, you can use [cleanup function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#my-cleanup-logic-runs-even-though-my-component-didnt-unmount) for that.

So given the OP question, the answer would be like:

```
 import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

    const WhiteBoard = () => {
      const canvasid = useRef();

      useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasid.current;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.font = "30px Impact";
        ctx.rotate(0.1);
        ctx.fillText("Awesome!", 50, 100);

        // Draw line under text
        var text = ctx.measureText("Awesome!");
        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(50, 102);
        ctx.lineTo(50 + text.width, 102);
        ctx.stroke();
        
        // add this
        return () => {ctx.reset()}
      }, []);

      return (
        <>
          <div>WhiteBoard</div>
          <canvas ref={canvasid} style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}></canvas>
        </>
      );
    };

    export default WhiteBoard;
```

Although i didn't test the code, it should be clear that cleanup function will fix the rendering twice issue.

Comment: I think the cleanup function should call `ctx.reset()`, instead of clearing the rectangle. Otherwise, the transformation matrix will have the rotation applied twice.

Comment: Hmmm. you're right. I'll edit it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

React is in strict mode so it re-rendered the Component Twice.
Removing `React.StrictMode` from index.js file fixed the issue

Comment: This isn't a real fix--StrictMode is there to help you detect bugs like this and should be kept in. Removing it doesn't fix anything, it just stifles the error that it's revealed. The real problem is missing a cleanup function in the `useEffect`.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to this answer. Maybe it's because of StrictMode.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71982736/9546759