# Unexpected behavior when using setInterval function in React useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, settimeout

**UPDATE** -
None of the responses to the duplicated questions provide an explanation for how the line `return () => { clearInterval(id); };` resolves the issue. Instead, they simply suggest removing the strict mode to fix it. Can anyone offer a detailed explanation for this solution, rather than repeating the advice to remove the `<React.StrictMode>` from the App?

**QUESTION** - I'm encountering a peculiar behavior in my React application when using a cleanup function in conjunction with setInterval inside a useEffect hook. Specifically, when I hide the cleanup function, the count is always **incrementing by two instead of one**. However, when I add the cleanup function, the count increments by one as expected.

Here's the code snippet:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Timer() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    }, 1000);
    // When the cleanup function below is uncommented, everything works as expected.
    // return () => {
    //   clearInterval(id);
    // };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Timer">
      <h2>Timer Two</h2>
      <h3>{count}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Timer;
```

I've noticed that removing `<React.StrictMode>` from `index.js` resolves the issue without the need for the cleanup function.

Can anyone shed light on why this behavior is occurring? What is the role of `<React.StrictMode>` in this context? I'd appreciate any insights or solutions to help me understand and address this issue. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to add to the [docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-re-running-effects-in-development) on this

Comment: One of the many duplicate questions: [React Hooks: useEffect() is called twice even if an empty array is used as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar)

Comment: https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode

Comment: All the answers of the duplicated questions don't explain why the `return () => { clearInterval(id); };` is fixing the issue !! they are just saying remove the strict mode and it will work !! can anyone explain (if anyone really knows more than **THIS IS A DUPLICATE QUESTION!!**  just remove the strict mode)

Comment: it fixes the issue by clearing up the interval - as you should - so that no matter what happens you never have a second identical function running every second. *that* is what is causing the count to increment by 2, and bugs such as this is exactly what StrictMode is supposed to make easier to diagnose. It's doing its job well here.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, **<React.StrictMode>** is like a helper for developers in React. It makes problems more noticeable during development but doesn't affect the final app. It's there to help find and fix issues early to make the app better.