# how to avoid useEffect to triger route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, i found the code like the following situation will trigger the route alert the messages twice (please ignore the redux code), do anyone know how to avoid that?

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { counterReducer } from './redux/counter';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

// Create Redux store
const store = createStore(counterReducer);
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>

        <App />

    </Provider>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: 
reportWebVitals();
```

--------------app.js-------------

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { increment, decrement } from './redux/counter';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';


function App({ count, increment, decrement }) {

    const [test, setTest] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Check if the user is logged in
        setTest('test')

    },[]);
    const Messages = () => {

        alert('This is the Messages component!!!!!!!!');


        //return null; // or any other JSX you want to render (if needed)
    };

    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/messages" element={<Messages />} />
                <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            </Routes>

            <div>
                <h1>Hello World!</h1>
                <p>Counter: {count}</p>
                <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
                <button onClick={decrement}>Decrement</button>
            </div>

            <div className="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li> <Link to="/">Home</Link> </li>
                    <li> <Link to="/messages">Messages</Link> </li>
                    <li> <Link to="/about">About</Link> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        count: state,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    increment,
    decrement,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: React.Strict mode is already removed. Please re open this question

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that React.Strict mode is not on

> StrictMode renders components twice (on dev but not production) in order to detect any problems with your code and warn you about them (which can be quite useful).

You may find a React.Strict node wrapping yours app like so:

```
function ExampleApplication() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <React.StrictMode>
        <div>
          <ComponentOne />
          <ComponentTwo />
        </div>
      </React.StrictMode>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Just remove `<React.Strict` node.

Comment: StrictMode was already removed from index.js long time ago

Comment: Try to look over the other reasons for this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar)