# How setState works?

Tags: reactjs

In the code below, I expected:

```yaml
state: 0
state: 1
```

But, result is:

```yaml
state: 0
state: 1
state: 1
```

I thought `setState` works only once(`0 -> 1`). But `1 -> 1` works again.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  console.log('state: ', state);

  useEffect(() => {
     setState(1);
  }, [state])
  
  return <></>
```

I tried another case. Set state to 1 on scroll event.

In this case, result is what I expected.

```yaml
state: 0
state: 1
```

```js
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  console.log('state: ', state);

  const onScroll = () => {
    setState(1)
  }
  
  return (
    ...
    onScroll={onScroll}
  )
```

What's the difference between the examples? (react version: 18.2.0)

Comment: Think about what the dependency `[state]` is doing in the `useEffect`.

Comment: useEffect runs twice (0 -> 1), (1 -> 1). But, In this point, setState triggered rerendering 1 -> 1 case either. I wanna know the reason why same value triggers rerender @StaticBeagle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks: useEffect() is called twice even if an empty array is used as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar) - probably strict mode

Comment: @ChrisHamilton It has nothing to do with strict mode. The output would be much different in that case.

Answer (score 2):

If you leave the dependencies array empty, React re-render only once.

```js
let loaded = false;

function re() {
  if (loaded) return 're-';

  loaded = true;
  return '';
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);
  console.log(re() + 'rendered, state:', state);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('  Effect set up');
    setState((prev) => {
      console.log(`    state is changing: ${prev} -> ${1}`);

      return 1;
    });

    return () => { console.log('  Effect clean up'); };
  }, []);
  
  return '';
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

But if you provide a `state` to the dependency array or omit the array, Effect is called again and call `setState` with the same value.

```js
let loaded = false;

function re() {
  if (loaded) return 're-';

  loaded = true;
  return '';
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);
  console.log(re() + 'rendered, state:', state);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('  Effect set up');
    setState((prev) => {
      console.log(`    state is changing: ${prev} -> ${1}`);

      return 1;
    });

    return () => { console.log('  Effect clean up'); };
  });
  
  return '';
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

When state is changed with the same value, the body of the component code runs again. And React DOES NOT re-render after the same thing happens.

```js
let loaded = false;

function re() {
  if (loaded) return 're-';

  loaded = true;
  return '';
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);
  console.log(re() + 'rendered, state:', state);

  return <button onClick={() => {
    console.log('state: ', state);
    setState(1);
  }}>setState(1)</button>;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Then, even though setState same value with previous value, it causes re-rendering if setState is in useEffect?

Comment: ```changes the state of state```, but it does not change the state, it was 1 its still 1. This does not explain why re-render happens again when (1 -> 1). With your logic if you remove the dependency array it will run an infinite loop. But this won't happen, because setting a state with the same value does not cause rerender,

Comment: @이명주 I've updated answer. Thank you for the correction, Oktay.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a state with the same value does not cause rerender. In your case this is not a rerender. It just executes the body of the component without going deep to its children and without the hooks. It is mentioned in the documentation

https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update

> Bailing out of a state update
> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)
>
> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again
> before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t
> unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree.

Also check this: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14810

Answer (score 0):

To get the expected result, the dependency array should be empty, so that the logic inside the useffect will be executed only once.

`useEffect(() => { setState(1); }, [])`

Also, it is redundant to keep the same state (which is updated inside useEffect logic) in dependency array