# React child component API call in useEffect invoked twice on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React app with multiple tabs/sections, each represented by its own child component and clicking on any of them loads that child component and immediately makes an API call to get some response and populate it's fields.

The parent component looks like below:

```
const defaultTabs = {
    section1: false,
    section2: false,
    section3: false
}
```

Now on click of refresh of the parent page, following code is invoked (kind of makes the API call again):

```
setMyTabs(defaultTabs);
setMyTabs(prev => ({...defaultTabs, [selectedTabId]: true}));
```

In my parent component JSX, I have:

```
{myTabs.section2 && <div><MySection2Component hasLoaded={hasLoaded} updateDateTime={updateDateTime} {...props} /></div>}
```

My child component (section2) looks like below:

```
const [mySection2Obj, setMySection2Obj] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    makeApiCall();
}, []);
    
useEffect(() => {
    props.hasLoaded(!isChildLoading);
}, [isChildLoading]);


async function makeApiCall() {
    const urlMain = myUrl + "/section2/endpoint";        
    const result = await ReactCall.post(urlMain);
    responseHandler(result);
    setIsChildLoading(false);
    if (result.data) {
        let mySection2Response = result?.data?.result?.sections.find(item => item.id === 'section-2');
        setMySection2Obj({
            ...mySection2Obj,
            attr1: mySection2Response?.fields?.attr1,
            attr2: mySection2Response?.fields?.attr2
        });
        props.updateDateTime(`Refreshed at ${result?.data?.refreshDateTime}`);
    }
}
```

Now the issue is, for some reason, the API call is being made twice.
Not sure why that is the case. But I did try wrapping around some of the functions inside useCallback. But that did not help.

Just to add, I want that the API call should be triggered only for:

1. On first app/parent component load OR
2. When user explicitly refreshes by clicking icon in the parent component.

Comment: Is the [React.Strict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60619061/637367) mode is on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks: useEffect() is called twice even if an empty array is used as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar)

Comment: @Wraithy - I do not have Strict mode on...So the issue seems to be something else