# Nextjs useEffect fired twice with searchParams deps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a next code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    doSearch();
    console.log(searchParams).
}, [searchParams]);
```

`doSearch` function fired twice because `useEffect` also fired twice. im sure that i dont change `searchParams`
Components looks like

```
export default function SearchComponent({ params, searchParams }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    doSearch();
    console.log(searchParams); // there all search params available on both cases so i cant check params on this step...
  }, [searchParams]);

  const doSearch = () => {//some actions}
}
```

Why its fired twice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks: useEffect() is called twice even if an empty array is used as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar)

Comment: Is `searchParams` an object? If so, is it memoized somehow in order not to get recreated for every render? My guess is that it is a new object reference every time, so it is not considered 'equal' to the previous version, even if its properties have the same values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const initialized = useRef(false)

useEffect(() => {
  if (!initialized.current) {
    

    // My actual effect logic...
    ...
  } else {
    initialized.current = true
  }
}, [searchParams])
```

From [React Hooks: useEffect() is called twice even if an empty array is used as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar) Solve my issue

Answer (score 3):

Are you using React 18 in `StrictMode`? And are you talking about development mode?

Because effects firing twice in `<React.StrictMode />` was added in React 18.

**It is a feature during development mode** to make sure you don't have unexpected side effects, etc:

> StrictMode currently helps with:
>
> - Identifying components with unsafe lifecycles
> - Warning about legacy string ref API usage
> - Warning about deprecated findDOMNode usage
> - Detecting unexpected side effects
> - Detecting legacy context API Ensuring reusable state

You can read more about it here:
https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state

Also discussed in one issue on Next.js Github Repo:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/35822