# Basic React app is triggering useEffect twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, webpack-dev-server

I've searched around and all the similar posts either dont apply or have no effect. I have a very simplified React app (v18.2.0) and im wanting to do some API calls and other logic in my app on render using useEffect. My understanding is this should only trigger once when providing an empty array as a param.

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./src/App";

import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);
```

App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("trigger app");
  }, []);

  return <div />;
};

export default App;
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My App</title>
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "main.js",
  },
  target: ["web", "es5"],
  stats: { children: true },
  devServer: {
    port: "9500",
    static: ["./public"],
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    liveReload: true,
  },
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

Looked into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar), Ive verified im not using Strict Mode, there doesnt seem to be anything that is triggering a re-render, and the component isnt being used more than once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why useEffect running twice and how to handle it well in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react)

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://taig.medium.com/prevent-react-from-triggering-useeffect-twice-307a475714d7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UseEffect hooks are always executed at least two times. Even when you use an empty dependency array

```
useEffect(()=>{}, [])
```

The first time it executes before the component is mounted on the DOM, and the second time is after it gets mounted into the DOM.

If you want overcome this, and only run your `useEffect` one time, apply a custom hook to detect if the component is mounted or not.

Usually, people apply this as a reusable custom hook using a ref. Or they apply the logic right into their code by using `useState()`

It's pretty simple to create:

Using state:

```
const [mounted, setMounted] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);
  if (!mounted) return <Button disabled label="Please wait..."/>;
  else return <Button enabled />;
```

Or if you want, Using refs:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default function useIsMounted() {
  const didMountRef = useRef(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    didMountRef.current = true
  })

  return Boolean(didMountRef.current)
}
```

You can then use it in any component you want to detect if the component is mounted or not:

```
import useIsMounted from '@lib/useIsMounted'
const App = ()=> {
  const isMounted = useIsMounted()
  useEffect(()=> {
    if(!isMounted) return
    // else, here, execute the following code only once, and after mount:
    console.log("you'll see me once if you disable strict mode")
  }, [])
}
```

If you want, there's already an npm package for this hook, you can download it [from here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-is-mounted-ref):

```bash
$ npm i use-is-mounted-ref
```

Then in the same way:

```
import useIsMounted from 'use-is-mounted-ref';

// ... etc
```

Using the reusable custom hook approach with ref is the ultimate solution for any scenario in my experience.

Comment: I've tried all of these examples and in every situation my console shows up twice. I've even c/p the example from the `use-is-mounted-ref` library and the fetch triggers twice. :(

Comment: @kcdrez, tell me, did the `use-is-mounted-ref` solution solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` hook is called once after the component is mounted. Currently, a possible cause can be a [`<StrictMode>`](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode). Check your `app.jsx` to check whether it's enabled or not.

Strict mode runs in development mode and can be enabled by adding a component at the beginning of the application. It checks for potential problems in the code, such as possible memory leaks, and warns the user about their presence.

Comment: I've included the snippet that is my app.js. Im assuming its set to false as the default and if thats the case then its set to false.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue, my webpack was essentially including my main script file twice so EVERYthing was basically triggering twice.

Using the `use-is-mounted-ref` library did the trick. Thanks everyone!