# why useEffect rendering twice in next.js application

Tags: typescript, next.js

in my next.js application I want to check if a user is allowed to access a page or not. I used a context but my useEffect return both the updated and the default value. how can I return only the last value.

This is my guard page:

```
"use client";
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { tokenServices } from "./services";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

type JWTContextType = {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
};

const AuthContext = createContext<JWTContextType>({
  isAuthenticated: false,
});

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const hasAccess = tokenServices.getToken();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasAccess) {
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
    } else if (!hasAccess) {
      setIsAuthenticated(false);
    }
  }, [pathname, hasAccess]);
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated }}>
      <>{children}</>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
export { AuthContext, AuthProvider };
```

This is my layout page:

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { AuthProvider } from "./GuestGuard";
import { ProtectedRoutes } from "./protectedRoutes";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
  manifest: "/manifest.json",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <AuthProvider>
        <ProtectedRoutes>
          <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
        </ProtectedRoutes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I expect the useEffect to return a single value

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar

Comment: @RogueMan I have already disabled reactStrictMode, the only possibility is that something higher up the tree is unmounting and remounting. but I don’t know what it means

Comment: It means that a parent component is rerendering. which also makes the child rerender.
But this wouldn't be the case in your situation as the layout page already is the top component.

Comment: @RogueMan The problem may be that the component is initially rendered on the server, it uses the initial state. However, when the client-side code updates the state, the server-rendered component still uses the old state. They suggest to check if the component is mounted before setting the state but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In my new guard page my useEffect return only the updated value by setting isAuthenticated initial value to undefined. I return children only when isAuthenticated is different by undefined. My useEffect still rendering multiple times but I saw that everytime I use useEffect the condition inside it return multiple times even when the code is simple.  It seems as if I can't fix this problem

```js
"use client";
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { tokenServices } from "./services";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

type JWTContextType = {
  isAuthenticated: boolean | undefined;
  isLoading: boolean;
};

const AuthContext = createContext<JWTContextType>({
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isLoading: true,
});

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<boolean | undefined>();
  const hasAccess = tokenServices.getToken();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsAuthenticated(!!hasAccess);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [isAuthenticated, pathname]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated, isLoading }}
    >
      <>{isAuthenticated !== undefined && children}</>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AuthContext, AuthProvider };
```

This is my new layout page:

```js
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { AuthProvider } from "./AuthGuard";
import { ProtectedRoutes } from "./protectedRoutes";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
  manifest: "/manifest.json",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <ProtectedRoutes>{children}</ProtectedRoutes>
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're encountering with useEffect returning both the default and updated values is likely due to the way your state is initialized and then updated based on the asynchronous retrieval of the token. When you're working with asynchronous operations and state updates in React, the component can render with initial state before the operation completes, and then re-render with the new state once it updates.

To ensure that only the latest value is used, you could:

1. Initialize your state based on the synchronous call to check for the token, if that's possible. This would set the initial state correctly without waiting for an effect to run.
2. Use a loading state to prevent the rendering of your protected content until the token check is complete.

Try this one:

```
"use client";
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { tokenServices } from "./services";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

type JWTContextType = {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  isLoading: boolean; // New state for loading
};

const AuthContext = createContext<JWTContextType>({
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isLoading: true, // Assume loading initially
});

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); // New state for loading
  const pathname = usePathname();

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAccess = async () => {
      const hasAccess = await tokenServices.getToken(); // Assuming this is an async call
      setIsAuthenticated(!!hasAccess);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    checkAccess();
  }, [pathname]);

  // If loading, don't render children or whatever you prefer
  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, isLoading }}>
      <>{children}</>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AuthContext, AuthProvider };
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, when I use your code my page loads endlessly and in the console appears this error "invariant expected app router to be mounted". Await in checkAccess function has no effect

Comment: there might be an issue with the way routing is being handled. Since `usePathname` is being used from next/navigation, and you are seeing this error, it implies that the router may not be properly initialized when the `AuthProvider` is trying to use it. We can avoid using `usePathname` directly within the `AuthProvider`. Instead, we can rely on Next.js's `useRouter` hook.

I will update my answer with the `useRouter` hook. give it a try.

Comment: Also another question, is `tokenServices.getToken()`  asynchronous? If `tokenServices.getToken()` is a synchronous function and doesn't return a promise, then you do not necessarily need an `isLoading` state because the state can be updated immediately without waiting for any asynchronous operation.

Comment: tokenService.getToken is this function:                                                                  export function getToken() {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    return localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
  }
}

Comment: I think my problem is the state that handle if I’m authenticated. its default value always returns to me and the updated value too

Comment: Have you tried using `useRouter` hook?

Comment: yes, i tried to import useRouter from next/router but when i use it i received this error: NextRouter was not mounted