# Load more functionality in react shows a error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to get a Load More functionality  to work .Basically I want to keep adding to a list that is initially there.I want to start with displaying details of 2 person and then on the click of add more button ,I want to keep on adding the rest of users.But initially when I load I end up with duplicated results and the the functionality works as intended.`// LOAD MORE IN REACT

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const LoadMoreComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [totalPage, setTotalPage] = useState(0);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${page}&per_page=2`
        );
        const result = await response.json();
        setLoading(false);
       setData((prev) =>[...prev , ...result.data]);
        setTotalPage(result.total_pages);
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [page]);

  return (
    <div>
    <div>
     {data && data.map((user) => (
      <div key={user.id}>
       <h3>
       {user.first_name}
        {user.last_name}
        </h3>
       </div>
          ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        {page < totalPage && (
          <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}> Load More </button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoadMoreComponent;
```

[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAPYn.png)

Comment: Your code works fine for me [playground](https://playcode.io/1801742)

Answer (score 0):

Your useEffect hook is getting called twice in mounting and it make 2 requests and duplicate your initial data. if you wonder why the reason is react `StrictMode` that makes your useEffect called again only in develop mode and not in product after react version 18. [StrictMode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode)

so when your code is rendered your data array has 4 members instead of 2.

if you want to remove it you can just remove `StrictMode` tag which is wrapping your `App`.

change your `index.js` file from

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

to

```
root.render(<App />);
```

for more info you may check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar)

Comment: Removing `StrictMode` should be the last route to take because `StrictMode` helps spot bugs early in development. Best bet is to use a library like [@tansack/react-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tanstack/react-query) async data fetching

Comment: @remedy_man You are right. i just wanted him to remove it and see the result so he can understand his code. Never said its the best approach. and about the code that you commented in question it works for you because you don't have `<StrinctMode> ` tag wrapping your `<App/>` in `index.js` file.

Comment: You are correct, `StrictMode` did not come to me when I reproduced his error.