React component does not load redux state
everyone! I'm faced with the problem that my component is rendered twice. I found out that it happens because of using useEffect and useSelector at the same time, but I don't know how to fix it. I'm not using React.StrictMode.
import React, {useEffect, useMemo, useState} from "react";
import {useIntl} from "react-intl";
import Typography from "../../../components/Typography";
import Card from "../../../components/Card";
import CardTitle from "../../../components/CardTitle";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import songActions from 'app/actions/song'

function List() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const {
        formatMessage,
    } = useIntl();


    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(songActions.fetchSongs());
    }, [])

    const reduxState = useSelector((store) => store);

    console.log(reduxState);

    return (
        <>
            <Typography>
                {formatMessage({ id: 'title' })}
            </Typography>
            {/*<div>*/}
            {/*    { songs.map(item => {*/}
            {/*        <Card>*/}
            {/*            <CardTitle>*/}
            {/*                ${item.id}*/}
            {/*            </CardTitle>*/}
            {/*        </Card>*/}
            {/*    })}*/}
            {/*</div>*/}
        </>
    );
}

export default List;

I've tried to use useRef in useUpdateEffect.js like this:
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react"

export default function useUpdateEffect(callback, dependencies) {
  const firstRenderRef = useRef(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRenderRef.current) {
      firstRenderRef.current = false
      return
    }
    return callback()
  }, dependencies)
}

And it is not render component twice but my data is not fetching because of this.
CHANGED!
Well, I figured out the double-loading error, but then another one appeared. This code should display cards with the values of objects with redux state. But an empty div is displayed. How can I fix it?

Here is the updated code of component:
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {useIntl} from "react-intl";
import Typography from "../../../components/Typography";
import Card from "../../../components/Card";
import CardTitle from "../../../components/CardTitle";
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";

function List() {
    const {
        formatMessage,
    } = useIntl();


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Hello');
    }, [])

    const songs = useSelector((store) => store.song.songs);

    return (
        <>
            {}
            <Typography>
                {formatMessage({ id: 'title' })}
            </Typography>
            <div>
                {songs.map(item => {
                    <Card>
                        <CardTitle>
                            ${item.id}
                        </CardTitle>
                    </Card>
                })}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default List;


"I'm not using React.StrictMode." you should be.

Hello, you should find a solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618844/react-hooks-useeffect-is-called-twice-even-if-an-empty-array-is-used-as-an-ar?rq=2

Besides seeing multiple console.logs in the console, what issue is being caused by rendering twice?   Also,  I would imagine that you don't really want all of your reduxState in this component.  To decrease renders you should select values from your store.  const myValue = useSelector(store => store.myValue)  <-- that will reduce re-renders to only when myValue  updates instead of when any value in the store updates.

I totally agree with @ScottZ. See Identity function (state => state) check for details why this is considered a mistake. The issue I see in your code is the console log in the component body as an unintentional side-effect so you're not getting a true measure of 1 console log per render to the DOM (e.g. the expensive part).

You have missed something there in map function.
you should write like this.
{songs.map(item => (
  <Card>
    <CardTitle>
      {item.id}
    </CardTitle>
  </Card>
))}

