Endpoint appears to be receiving data twice
I am trying to get started with Node.js.  I have created a simple page:
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function callApi() {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/data', {firstName: 'Fred', surname: 'Bloggs'}, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
      .then(response => {
        setData(response.data.message);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React and Node.js Integration</h1>
      <p>Message from the server: {data}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default callApi;

and a simple Node.js endpoint that handles post requests:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3001; 
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

app.post('/api/data', upload.none(), (req, res) => {
  const formData = req.body;
  console.log('form data', formData);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET,POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', 2592000); // 30 days
  const data = "Response from POST request: " + formData.firstName + " " + formData.surname
  res.json(data)
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
}); 

I don't think this is working properly because (1) Fred Bloggs is printed to the Terminal twice in Node.js even though there is only one call to console.log as shown below:

Also 'Response from POST request:Fred Bloggs' is not returned to the client.

And do you see two requests in the network tab? Is this in React strict mode? Why is the app making a post on component load anyway?

@jonrsharpe, I see two requests in Fiddler.  I am just trying to get a post request working (that is why it is posting in page load).

If the client is making two requests why do you think the server's the problem? It's receiving the number of requests that there are. Why is multer involved? And given you're responding with a string why expect a message property?! Do some basic debugging - at the very least you should be able to narrow it down to which side of the HTTP boundary each thing is happening.

Most likely dupes e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60618844/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/72238175/3001761, ... as the main problem is the hook running twice (and nothing to do with the server "receiving" the wrong number of requests).

The issue you are experiencing with is related React Development mode - not NodeJS itself.
The primary reason for useEffect executing twice is the strict mode in React's development mode. This mode intentionally invokes lifecycle methods and effects multiple times to help identify problems. It's a feature designed to aid developers, not a bug. For example, it is common to subscribe events in useEffect and forget to clean them on unmount, which causes a memory leak. Double invocation in dev mode helps to identify such mistakes at an early stages.
It only happens in Dev mode not in Prod build.
It might be confusing initially, but I don't see much problem sending 2 requests in dev mode.
Here are more details explained by React Team. Info
In your case, you can use AbortController to cancel previous requests on unmount or re-render, and pass it as a cleanup function. This will help avoid delivering the first request to the server in dev mode. In general, it's a good practice to have cancel request functionality in place because when a component is destroyed, you no longer need that request to be completed.
Here is the code to achieve that.
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function callApi() {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;

    axios
      .post(
        'http://localhost:3001/api/data',
        { firstName: 'Fred', surname: 'Bloggs' },
        {
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
          signal, // <== Pass the signal to the axios request
        },
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data.message);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
          // We need to ignore this error, since it is fired by cancel signal
          console.info('Request canceled', error.message);
        } else {
          setError(error.message); // It's a server error
        }
      });

    // Cleanup function to cancel the request on component unmount or re-render
    return () => {
      controller.abort(); // Cancel the request
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React and Node.js Integration</h1>
      <p>Message from the server: {data}</p>
      {error && <p>Error: {error}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default callApi;


How do you test the application if the endpoint is called twice? Is there a way to modify my code so the endpoint isn't called twice? I am thinking that my code goes against Reacts values so needs to be changed.

If you are extremely uncomfortable with the feature you can remove StrictMode and it won't duplicate requests. But I don't understand why it causes you problems. You send a request on the component mount and you call setData which sets initial data, after that, it sends the same request again and you call setData once again, and it overwrites it - no duplicated data. To my understanding it should not be a problem for testing, you going to see 2 requests in the Network tab, that's all.

If I submit a post request that causes a database insert in a rest api, then wouldn't there be two database inserts? +1 by the way.

Yes, but that is a very exceptional case. If you are inserting data into DB for every component mount then you definitely need to disable strict mode. There is no other way, that's how React 18 and above works.

thanks.  I am learning react in my spare time.  I have already upvoted the question, but before I accept - can the React code be amended so data isn't inserted "on every mount".

Yes, I believe you can use AbortController for that. I update the post

Since React 18, the Strict mode provoke api call to be triggered twice to ensure a correct behaviour of your application. You can try disabling it to be sure. In a basic react app, you should find something like :
createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);

Remove or comment the StrictMode component And check again.
If you are using NextJs, then you can edit your next.config.js file as follow to disable the StrictMode :
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

I don't know if the file exists in a default project but can still add it manually I guess. Here is the link to the documentation.

I used the following command to create the React project: npx create-next-app@latest.  I have done a global search in vscode for the word: "strict" and find no results.

Every course I have looked at so far (4) suggests a different command for creating a React project.

@w0051977 I don't know about nextJs, you should have add this tag to your question to avoid misleading. Consider NextJs as a wrapper around React. It's still react, but Next will do things under the hood and provide additional features. I Edited my answer to include NextJs in the operation
